# print a jagged array from a file

Tags: java

i am trying to print a jagged array just like my txt file is. I have already found the rows I was told to create a 2d array now with just the rows since we don't know the columns yet and then find the doubles there are in the file.

```
        double[][] arr = new double[rows][];

        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner (file);   

        int i =  0;
        while (scanner2.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner2.nextLine();
            Scanner newLine = new Scanner(newLine);

            int countDoubles = 0;
            while(scanner2.hasNextDouble()){
                countDoubles++;
            }
    

            double[] doubleArr = new double[countDoubles];

            newLine = new Scanner(newLine);


            // populate doubleArr using newLine


            arr[i]=doubleArr;
            i++;

        }

        //how I counted the col on a normal 2d array file 
      

        String in = scanner.nextLine();
        String [] out = in.split(" ");
        for (int s = 0; s < out.length; s++){
            col++;
       

        //printing the array

        for(int k = 0; k < rows; k++) {       
            for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = scanner2.nextDouble();
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
               
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: I can't use an arraylist and the file the values are just seperated by spaces and is exactly in jagged format

Comment: To answer your question, this line `while (scanner2.hasNextLine()){` is already populating your array line by line (like you were told) when you use `arr[i]=doubleArr;` to insert your split doubles into the 2d array. It looks fine to me.

Comment: I edited it how I counted the columns on a regular 2d array will i just do that under it then?

Comment: Q: It would really help to see an example of your text file.  A snippet: just enough to "see what the data looks like".  SUGGESTION: I would strongly consider using a list (e.g. ArrayList) instead of arrays.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error full message

Comment: that's the catch it says error cause that's what I have printed in the catch

Comment: You need to print the error instead, for example `e.printStackTrace();`, but I can see what is happening, your while loop is only reading every second line, which means you are using `scanner2.nextLine();` twice inside your while loop, which you must not do. Edit your question to include ALL of your current updated code, or use the code in my answer exactly as it is because that does work.

Comment: I deleted the split thing and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three main issues, firstly all the column code needs to go within the while loop so that it is done for every line of the file. Secondly, you were getting stuck in a loop here `while(scanner2.hasNextDouble()){`, and lastly, there were a bunch of code errors that I have corrected below, but specifically you can't reference a Scanner to itself `Scanner newLine = new Scanner(newLine);` it should refer to the string from the previous line `Scanner newLine = new Scanner(line);`

Here is a working example using as much of your code as possible:

```
    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(file);

    //Get total lines
    int count = 0;
    while (scanner2.hasNextLine()) {
        count++;
        scanner2.nextLine();
    }

    //Create the array with the correct length
    double[][] arr = new double[count][];

    //Reset the scanner:
    scanner2 = new Scanner(file);

    int i =  0;
    //Loop thorugh the file one line at a time
    while (scanner2.hasNextLine()){
        //Get the current line
        String line = scanner2.nextLine();
        //Changed this line to correctly reference "line", not "newLine"
        //Note that you don't need to use scanner here, you could just split the line and use a for loop to go through it
        Scanner newLine = new Scanner(line);

        int countDoubles = 0;
        //Changed this line to reference the correct scanner "newLine"
        while(newLine.hasNextDouble()){
            countDoubles++;
            //Consume the double so that the code advances, otherwise it will just loop for ever
            newLine.nextDouble();
        }

        double[] doubleArr = new double[countDoubles];
        //This line vas incorrectly referring to the wrong thing, it should be "line", not "newLine"
        newLine = new Scanner(line);
    
        //Use a "for" loop here inside of the while loop to store the column data per each line of the file
        for (int y = 0; y < countDoubles; y++)
        {
            doubleArr[y] = newLine.nextDouble();
        }

        // populate doubleArr using newLine
        arr[i]=doubleArr;
        i++;
    }

    //Code that deals with data needs to be inside the while loop, see the edits above
    //String in = scanner.nextLine();
    //String [] out = in.split(" ");
    //for (int s = 0; s < out.length; s++){
    //    col++;
    //
    ////printing the array
    //for(int k = 0; k < rows; k++) {       
    //    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    //        arr[i][j] = scanner2.nextDouble();
    //        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");      
    //    }
    //    System.out.println();
    //}

    //Now we can print the array dynamically by using the array length like so "k < arr.length" and "j < arr[k].length"
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[k].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[k][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Read through the code comments and you should get a better understanding of how this works.

With the above code I get the following output which matches a sample file I made:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 
4.0 5.0 
6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 
14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 
18.0 19.0 
20.0 
21.0 22.0
```

Comment: Thanks! i just edited and stuck with the newLine scanner since it was used throughout the code and put the split part inside the while loop which would I still use the col++ part in it? cause i did it and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: also why did u use specifically 10 on y < 10

Comment: Good spotting, I have updated it to `y < countDoubles`, also this line should be uncommented if you want the code in my answer to work `newLine = new Scanner(line);`, click [here to see the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70934666/revisions). Without seeing your updated code I can only guess what is wrong. Did you get any errors? Does it print out wrong?

Comment: I did keep that line uncommented, you said to put the split part and etc inside the while loop and I was asking if the col++ should also be there. I updated the code like yours just put the split columns part inside the loop at the end, the rest is the same that's why not sure about the split part. it runs but it's doing the catch instead of printing the array

Comment: I just did a quick check where the error seems to be by printing hello world and when I set it inside the for int y = 0 loop is where it doesn't print the message so something must be wrong there

Comment: the hello world doesn't print if i put it under the doubleArr[y]... part but when I put it on top of that line it does print but only once doesn't seem to be looping

Comment: If your file only has one line, or if it has invalid data then this could happen.

Comment: my file has 8 lines (rows)

Comment: Nevermind I made a mistake I had the wrong scanner now it does loop I just tried the printing hello world thing again and this time it doesn't print below this code: arr[i][j] = scanner2.nextDouble();

Comment: There were a couple of errors because I never tested the code, these have been updated (including removing `arr[i][j] = scanner2.nextDouble();`) and it should work now.

Comment: I did that and for some reason it's not printing the lines in between if you look at my edit and it's also doing the catch instead of continuing to the rest of my code